# How to combine component relative paths and systemjs?

Tags: angular, systemjs, commonjs

[Component relative paths](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-relative-paths.html) are a helpful tool. The reference example using module.id displayed in angular's webpage is for **commonjs**.

I'm using the [angular2-express-starter](https://github.com/vladotesanovic/angular2-express-starter) package and i can't use component relative paths. It seems that this is because the starter pack uses **systemjs**.

Any solution?

Comment: I think you can just change to commonjs in your tsconfig and everything should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

The solution, from this [github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6053#issuecomment-214163297):

```
declare var __moduleName: string;

@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    moduleId: __moduleName,
    templateUrl: './my.component.html'
})
export class MyComponent { }
```

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to my attention. If others are holding their nose as they consider using this workaround, as I was, the link in @Hernan's answer discusses why this hack is believed to be necessary. See robwormald's comment on May 28, for example. If you are just looking for a definitive statement of the workaround, see mlc-mlapis's final comment on Aug 7 in that same GitHub link. I like the use of `const` instead of `var` in the declaration.